# how to configure selenium record-play test in ci/cd pipeline of JAVA project using pom.xml?

Tags: maven, selenium, continuous-integration, continuous-testing

I am configuring chrome-driver and npm install selenium-side-runner in pom.xml and running a ci/cd pipeline in gitlab. 
Still I am getting "not found error"

Answer (score 0):

I have shared the link with you not possible to tell you about this, because this is so hard to explain any one hence shared the blog link so you can understand it by your own way..

https://www.visiontemenos.com/blog/selenium-ide